# The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, windowlistener

```
package in.ac.iitb.cfilt.hwnbrowser;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class WordListBox extends JPanel
    implements ActionListener, WindowListener
{

    public static void showList(String type, String list[], String labelText, String title)
    {
        frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(2);
        JComponent newContentPane = new WordListBox(type, list, labelText);
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        frame.addWindowListener(new  Object(type)   
    class _anm1 {}

);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent windowevent)
    {
    }

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowevent)
    {
    }

    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent windowevent)
    {
    }

    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent windowevent)
    {
    }

    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent windowevent)
    {
    }

    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent windowevent)
    {
    }

    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent windowevent)
    {
    }


}
```

---

```
 /*
    The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (Object)
    Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
    Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
    The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (Object)
    Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
    Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
    The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (Object)
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
    Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation
    Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
    The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (Object)
    Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
    Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
    The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (Object)
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
    Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation
    Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
    The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (Object)
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
    Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation
    Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
    The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (Object)
    Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
    Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
    The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (Object)
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
    Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation
    Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
    The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (Object)
    Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
    Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
    The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (Object)
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
    Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation
    Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
    The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (Object)
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
    Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation
    Syntax error on token ")", delete this token

    at in.ac.iitb.cfilt.hwnbrowser.WNBrowserMain.createMenuBar(WNBrowserMain.java:43)
    at in.ac.iitb.cfilt.hwnbrowser.WNBrowserMain.createAndShowGUI(WNBrowserMain.java:571)
    at in.ac.iitb.cfilt.hwnbrowser.WNBrowserMain.main(WNBrowserMain.java:928)*/
```

Answer (score 3):

```
frame.addWindowListener(new  Object(type)
```

Use `this` instead of `new Object()` as `addWindowListener` expects a `WindowListener` argument, and `this` refers to the `WindowListene` implemented class

```
frame.addWindowListener(this);
```

---

- Also, you have no reference to an `ActionListener actionPerformed` in your code, which you *need*. Of even your registering of an `ActionListener` to any component. You're not showing us something.
- Also I have absolutely no idea what this `class _anm1 {}` is trying to do. Get rid of it and just pass `this` as pointed out above.
- You're also going to have to get rid of the `static` in your method signature, as the class referenced in the method (this) isn't `static`. If you have a bunch of unnecessary `static` fields and `static` method in your class, then you have a problem, and a big refactor ahead of you (depending on how bad it is).
- Do a Google search on [difference between instance field and static field in Java](https://www.google.com/search?q=google%20guave%20torrent#q=difference+between+instance+field+and+static+field+in+Java) and read some of the results that come up.
- Any other problems, and we'll have to see more code.